# Simple form validation with PHP - Login Screen

Tags: php, html

I know there is many ways to do a login form validation with mysql, but i'm trying to make a simple form validation with php. I'm getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in
>   C:\xampp2\htdocs\one\homedir\public_html\calendario\valida.php on line
>   11

Here is my form:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/HgflTDf.jpg") 50% fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

@keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(359deg);
  }
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgba(4, 40, 68, 0.85);
}

.login {
  border-radius: 2px 2px 5px 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 320px;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.login.loading button {
  max-height: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.login.loading button .spinner {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 40%;
}
.login.ok button {
  background-color: #8bc34a;
}
.login.ok button .spinner {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  height: 20px;
  animation: none;
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
}
.login input {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  transition: border-width 0.2s ease;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #ccc;
}
.login input + i.fa {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -47px;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
}
.login input:focus {
  outline: none;
  color: #444;
  border-color: #2196F3;
  border-left-width: 35px;
}
.login input:focus + i.fa {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 30px;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}
.login a {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #2196F3;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.login .title {
  color: #444;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 10px 0 30px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.login button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-height: 60px;
  border: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
  transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  border-bottom-width: 7px;
}
.login button .spinner {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 4px solid #ffffff;
  border-top-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-radius: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  animation: spinner 0.6s infinite linear;
  transition: top 0.3s 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s 0.3s ease, border-radius 0.3s ease;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.login:not(.loading) button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #2196F3;
}
.login:not(.loading) button:focus {
  border-bottom-width: 4px;
}

footer {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ddd;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
footer a, footer a:link {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Calendário de E-mail marketing</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

  
   

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <form class="login" action="valida.php" method="post">
    <p class="title">Log in</p>
    <input id="usuario" class="usuario" type="text" placeholder="Usuário" autofocus/>
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <input id="senha" clas="senha" type="password" placeholder="Senha" />
    <i class="fa fa-key"></i>

    <button>
      <i class="spinner"></i>
      <span class="state">Log in</span>
    </button>
  </form>
  <footer>2017 One Imóveis de Luxo</footer>
  </p>
</div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

    

</body>
</html>
```

And, most important, here is my php file:

```html
<?php



$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];



if( ($usuario=='marketing') && ($senha=='onecia40012121') {
    echo header('Location: http://www.onecia.com.br/ato/?lead=ok');   THIS LINE HAVE A PROBLEM
} else {
    echo  "<script>alert('Login ou senha incorretos!');</script>";
}



?>
```

Wait for your help, thanks!

Comment: Missing `)` in the `if`.

Comment: you have missed closing round `)` bracket of if statement

Comment: ``php -l C:\xampp2\htdocs\one\homedir\public_html\calendario\valida.php`` will tell you syntax errors in the file.

Comment: @FirstOne I'm new to PHP, sorry but you don't know how much you helped me. Thanks!

Comment: Just waiting the time to mark as resolved, don't need to downvote guys!

Comment: `if( $usuario=='marketing' && $senha=='onecia40012121') {...` fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an `)` in your `if` statement.
Always use just as many `(` as `)` in your code.

```
<?php

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

if( ($usuario=='######') && ($senha=='######')) {
    echo header('Location: http://www.example.com.br/ato/?lead=ok');
} else {
    echo  "<script>alert('Login ou senha incorretos!');</script>";
}

?>
```

Oh, and it might be a good idea to remove your username, password and site url from your question.

Comment: @AgeDeo `THIS LINE HAVE A PROBLEM` should be commented

Comment: Yep you where right, I copied it from the question, changed it.

Comment: This question is probably just flaggable as a simple typographical error.

Comment: @FirstOne i admit i should've done more research before opening a topic. I accept the downvotes and i'll try to research more before opening a topic. Thanks to you and all the community for the instant help!

Comment: @PedroGusmão ok. Oh, just note that I haven`t voted on anything in this question yet.

Comment: Questions that are about basic PHP syntax errors should not be answered. They should be closed as a duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071) only.  See: [Should one advise on off topic questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232). Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution anyway.